# Pythonのmatplotlibで要素の名前をプロットしたい

Tags: python, r, matplotlib

Pythonのmatplotlib/seabornを使って散布図を描きたいのですが、ローマ字の都道府県名がDataframeのindexになっており、それを点としてプロットしたいと考えています。
Rの場合は例えばirisのデータですと、

```
>plot(iris[,1],iris[,3],type="n")
>text(iris[,1],iris[,3])
```

とすれば出力されますが、matplotlibなどの場合はどのようにすればよいのでしょうか？
調べては見たものの、matplotlibにはオプションが存在しないのか答えに行き着かない状態です。

現在は

```
plt.scatter(x, y)
```

でプロットした散布図の出力はmatplotlibでできている状態です。
よろしくお願いします。

****追記****
説明が足らず失礼しました。
プロットした点がただの丸やバツになるのではなく、それぞれの個体がそれぞれの名前になる（例えば北海道のデータを表す点が"hokkaido", 東京のデータを表す点が"tokyo"となる）ようなコードを書きたいです。イメージとしては　https://www1.doshisha.ac.jp/~mjin/R/06.html　のページの図12や13でしょうか。
現在はmatplotlibのみで書いていますがseabornでもどちらでも構わないです。
コードは明日アップします。

****追記****
Rの場合のコードです。　http://hnsn1202.hateblo.jp/entry/2013/02/10/041045　を参考に作成しました。
1列目が県名、2列目が収入、3列目が人口密度です。

```
library(data.table)
new <- fread("new.csv",header=TRUE)
plot(new[,2],new[,3],type="n")
text(new[,2],new[,3],new.label)

colnames(new) <- c("pre","income","mitsudo")
library(maptools)
new <- as.data.frame(new)
plot(new[,2],new[,3],type="n")
pointLabel(x=new[,2], y=new[,3], labels=new$pre)
```

Answer (score 1):

散布図のメソッドが分からない、という質問でしょうか？

> Seabornでは散布図は「jointplot」というメソッドで描画できます。

[pythonで美しいグラフ描画 -seabornを使えばデータ分析と可視化が捗る その1 - Qiita](http://qiita.com/hik0107/items/3dc541158fceb3156ee0#%E6%95%A3%E5%B8%83%E5%9B%B3)

散布図を書きたい、という意図は伝わったのですが、それ以上のことが分からないので、コードを共有されるとより適切な回答がつくと思います。

Answer (score 1):

`marker`に`mathtext`なる物を指定できます（こういう話ではないかもしれませんが）。

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y = [2**x for x in x]
plt.scatter(x, y, marker="$Tokyo$", s=20**2)
plt.show()
```

または`scatter`に拘らず、`text`, `annotate`, `plot`といったメソッドを使ってもよいのではないでしょうか。